# Poor Performance while data upsert to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I am submitting 3 million records to postgres table1 from a staging table table2,I have my update and insert queries as below

```
UPDATE table1 t set 
                          col1 = stage.col1,
                          col2 = stage.col2 , 
                          col3 = stage.stage.col3
                          from table2 stage
                          where t.id::uuid = stage.id::uuid
                          and coalesce(t.name,'name') = coalesce(stage.name,'name')
                          and coalesce(t.level,'level') = coalesce(stage.level,'level');
                          
                      
                      INSERT INTO table1 
                      (col1, 
                      col2, 
                      col3, 
                      col4, 
                      id, 
                      name,
                      level) 
                      select 
                      stage.col1,
                      stage.col2, 
                      stage.col3,
                      stage.col4, 
                      stage.id, 
                      stage.name, 
                      stage.level
                      from table2 stage
                      where NOT EXISTS (select 
                      from table1 t where
                      t.id::uuid = stage.id::uuid 
                      and coalesce(t.name,'name') = coalesce(stage.name,'name')
                      and coalesce(t.level,'level') = coalesce(stage.level,'level'));
```

I am facing performance issues (takes long 1.5 hours) even using the exactly same indexed keys (btree) as defined on the table, In order to test the cause ,I created a replica of the table1 without indexes and I was able to submit entire data in 15 ~ 17 mins approx., So I am inclined to think that indexes are killing the performance on the table as there are so many of them (some unused indexes which I cannot drop due to permission issues).I am looking for suggestions to improve/optimize my query or may be use some other strategy to upsert the data to reduce data load time. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Which part takes that long? The UPDATE or the INSERT? Did you try `insert ... on conflict` instead?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, I have observed both inserts and updates are taking long time (even if I have lesser data to update than insert),I have tried insert on conflict too in past but couldn't see a lot of performance gain, and one constraint I observed was, it only allows upsert on defined primary key index, the set of keys I am using is different that that

Comment: You can use `on conflict()` with any unique constraint or index, not just primary key

Comment: sorry @ a_horse_with_no_name ,I get the error "ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification" when I tried to perform on conflict query on the indexes which are not created as unique indexes,I am not a postgres expert,any suggestions on that ?

Comment: if you want to prevent duplicates  those indexes should be defined as unique

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Running an explain analyze on the query helped me to realize the query was never using the defined indexes on target table and was doing a sequential scan on a large number of rows  ,the cause was one of the keys used in update/insert was defined without a coalesce in the defined indexes , though it means I have to handle null well before feeding in to my code , but it improved the performance significantly. I am open to further improvements.